# TypeError: FileSystemFileHandle.queryPermission is not a function

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload, filesystems

I have a very simple function that opens a file as shown in the example on [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemHandle)

```
// fileHandle is a FileSystemFileHandle
// withWrite is a boolean set to true if write

async function verifyPermission(fileHandle, withWrite) {
  const opts = {};
  if (withWrite) {
    opts.mode = 'readwrite';
  }

  // Check if we already have permission, if so, return true.
  if (await fileHandle.queryPermission(opts) === 'granted') {
    return true;
  }

  // Request permission to the file, if the user grants permission, return true.
  if (await fileHandle.requestPermission(opts) === 'granted') {
    return true;
  }

  // The user did not grant permission, return false.
  return false;
}
```

but I keep getting an error saying that file.queryPermission is not a function. Here's my code:

```
let file = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
console.log(file.queryPermission({ mode: 'readwrite' }));
```

I've also tried putting the `console.log` in a `.then` but had the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox or Safari or older versions of other browsers, then according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemHandle/queryPermission) and [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_filesystemhandle_querypermission) `queryPermission` is not supported in these browsers.
Perhaps you should check your browser's support for this feature.